# Swift 3 extension with a floating point array

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

I'm trying to extend an `Array<Float>` in Swift 3. The goal is to add a function and call a few `self.append()` statements in the body. Here's what I have so far:

```
extension Array where Element: FloatingPoint {

    mutating func test(a: Float) {
        self.append(a)
    }

}
```

I'm getting an error that `append()` needs a `FloatingPoint`, and that it cannot use `Float`. But doesn't the `Float` type conform to `FloatingPoint`? Btw in Swift 2.X, I extended `_ArrayType` which worked well. It seems to have disappeared in Swift 3, and the `append()` function is now in `Array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only append elements to the array of type `Element`:

```
extension Array where Element: FloatingPoint {

    mutating func test(a: Element) {
        self.append(a)
    }

}
```

Note: This extension extends all floating point arrays: `[Double]`, `[CGFloat]`, ...